# lost password "user-pass" form no more redering

Tags: views, theming, forms

We didn't touch our templates and the "lost password" form is no more rendering. here is my template code working fine with `$login_form`.

```
<div id="login-container">
    <div class="login-hint">
      <p><?php echo t('Pour vous connecter, veuillez indiquer votre adresse email (login) et votre mot de passe')?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
      $login_form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Login');
      $login_form['pass']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Mot de passe');
      print drupal_render($login_form); 
    ?>
</div>
<div id="password-container">
    <div class="pass-reset-hint"><?php echo t('Indiquez votre adresse e-mail de connexion, et vous recevrez un nouveau mot de passe')?></div>
    <?php 
      $reset_pass_form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Addresse e-mail');
      //print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_pass'));
      print drupal_render($reset_pass_form); 
    ?>
</div>
```

I also tried directly the following :

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_pass'));
```

Here is the result of `print_r($reset_pass_form);` so, the it exists :

```
Array
(
    [#form_id] => user_pass
    [#type] => form
    [#build_id] => form-na8Ow30ky69azZcTP7vQ_BijkXKobSuPFtmsajrNveM
    [form_build_id] => Array
        (
            [#type] => hidden
            [#value] => form-na8Ow30ky69azZcTP7vQ_BijkXKobSuPFtmsajrNveM
            [#id] => form-na8Ow30ky69azZcTP7vQ_BijkXKobSuPFtmsajrNveM
            [#name] => form_build_id
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_build_id
                )

            [#input] => 1
            [#process] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ajax_process_form
                )

            [#theme] => hidden
            [#defaults_loaded] => 1
            [#tree] => 
            [#array_parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_build_id
                )

            [#weight] => 0
            [#processed] => 1
            [#required] => 
            [#attributes] => Array
                (
                )

            [#title_display] => before
            [#ajax_processed] => 
            [#sorted] => 1
        )

    [form_id] => Array
        (
            [#type] => hidden
            [#value] => user_pass
            [#id] => edit-user-pass
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_id
                )

            [#input] => 1
            [#process] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ajax_process_form
                )

            [#theme] => hidden
            [#defaults_loaded] => 1
            [#tree] => 
            [#array_parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_id
                )

            [#weight] => 0.001
            [#processed] => 1
            [#required] => 
            [#attributes] => Array
                (
                )

            [#title_display] => before
            [#name] => form_id
            [#ajax_processed] => 
            [#sorted] => 1
        )

    [#id] => user-pass
    [#method] => post
    [#action] => /login
    [#theme_wrappers] => Array
        (
            [0] => form
        )

    [#tree] => 
    [#parents] => Array
        (
        )

    [#validate] => Array
        (
        )

    [#submit] => Array
        (
        )

    [#theme] => Array
        (
            [0] => user_pass
        )

    [#processed] => 
    [#defaults_loaded] => 1
    [#required] => 
    [#attributes] => Array
        (
        )

    [#title_display] => before
    [#array_parents] => Array
        (
        )

    [#sorted] => 1
    [#attached] => Array
        (
            [js] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => setting
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                    [urlIsAjaxTrusted] => Array
                                        (
                                            [/login] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Is it an update issue or anonymous user rights issue?

I'm on 7.58

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

actually the user/password is accessible for everyone (unless some custom code changes this behaviour)

if the form elements are present in DOM but are not displayed, i would check if there is some custom css that hides it somehow.

Comment: I was thinking of the CSS `display:none`or soething like that bue, if I look for source code (with Firebug console) there's nothing! https://i.imgur.com/RjXFHdX.png

Comment: Here is the only code I have in `<form action="/login" method="post" id="user-pass--2" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-q5vjHEzfpleFhK4V3fuhxDpK8W-zH2zy6H8B0kTHOOU" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="user_pass" />
</div></form>`